# Do you recommend any good book about distributed systems and cloud computing?

Tags: azure, cloud, distributed-computing, distributed-caching, distributed-system

I'm learning about Microsoft Azure, and there are lots of concepts that, although are not new for me, I'd like to know more about them, like for example database sharding, denormalization, nosql, content delivery networks, distributed cache (like memcache), asynchronous processing, split systems, load balancing, etc... etc...

I'm looking for a book about approaches rather than technique.

The problem is that I can read a lot about how to use Azure Storage, or how to use Azure CDN, but without a correct approach, the result won't be as good as expected.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: "Questions asking us to recommend or find a tool, library or favorite off-site resource are off-topic for Stack Overflow as they tend to attract opinionated answers and spam. Instead, [describe the problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/q/139399/) and what has been done so far to solve it." Reference: [What topics can I ask about here?](http://stackoverflow.com/help/on-topic)

Comment: This post is 3 years old

Comment: I recognize that, but it's still off-topic.  No matter the age of the post, old posts are subject to the _same_ standards as new posts are, it just means nobody acknowledged it before.  Just wanted to let you know of that guideline.  Don't shoot the messenger, but these are the guidelines outlined in the help center.  If you have a question about that, you can post it on http://meta.stackoverflow.com/  Cheers.

Comment: If this post has not been closed already, it is probably because that rule did not exist three years ago. That link about "describe the problem" it is just one year and a half old, so  the other about the topics, that links the first, it is even newer. This is ridiculous.

Comment: Reference: http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/194116/should-i-vote-to-close-old-questions and http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/194219/should-i-flag-old-questions

Comment: Like I said, don't shoot the messenger, I was simply letting you know of the issue. Cheers.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Microsoft's Patterns and Practices group has put out several resources in the last year that you might want to take a look at.  They generally take an over-arching approach.  Here is a link to one of their resources on building applications on Windows Azure.

http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ff966499.aspx

Comment: Nice and cheap actually, http://www.amazon.com/Developing-Applications-Microsoft-Platform-Practices/dp/0735656061/ref=pd_bxgy_b_img_b

Comment: I've been taking a look and it's gonna be ver useful for me. Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

Some Books I can suggests are these. Not One book covers all concept so its kind of jam-it-up situation.

1. Singhal & Shivaratri, "Advanced Concept in Operating Systems", McGraw Hill
2. Ramakrishna,Gehrke,” Database Management Systems”, Mc Grawhill
3. Coulouris, Dollimore, Kindberg, "Distributed System: Concepts and Design”, Pearson
   Education
4. Tenanuanbaum, Steen,” Distributed Systems”, PHI
5. Gerald Tel, "Distributed Algorithms", Cambridge University Press

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

there are no book per se but there are a lot papers out there on distributed computing and cloud computing which can come handy. Otherwise if u want to go for books there is a three book volume from tenebaum titled distributed networks.

Comment: Do you mean 'Distributed Systems: Principles and Paradigms,' by Tanenbaum and Van Steen?